# save values in separate columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a  CSV dataset that one of its labels is like this picture.

[image]

How could I save these zeros and ones in separate columns?

I mean it should be like this picture:

[image]

Comment: That's not possible, either you have multiple columns each with their own heading, or you have only one column.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Actually, this is totally possible in a CSV, but I will edit my existing answer so it answers the OPs question.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that, to help future readers, if my answer helped, don't forget to accept it, which will add a green "accepted" checkmark to the answer and pin it to the top.

Comment: A csv is a text *comma separated values* file. You only show images of a spreasheet. Please show the original and expected files as **text**.

Comment: @Jonathan what would a CSV file look like which has 3 columns and the first two columns share one heading?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Simple, I can't really find a way to show it since GitHub Gist can't make my CSV "beautiful and searchable" if the columns aren't lined up, but [this](https://gist.github.com/zurgeg/5c1e4a5784d3e58bb01ff28a2f11b497) might give you a good "prototype" of what it looks like. I had to add a stray comma at the end though, which makes it look kinda ugly. I agree that you shouldn't do that if you can.

Comment: It is a pity that questions about CSV file do not show the file. Without knowing whether fields are quoted and what separator is used, it is impossible to provide a correct answer. At best, someone can try a wild guess that could work by accident (what Jonathan did) :-(

Comment: @Jonathan: what you showed (just clik the *raw* button to see the text) is a very nice csv file, with 2 rows and 3 fields per row. Because the first row does contain 2 commas so 3 fields. Simply the third field is an empty string. BTW fields in a text file (what a csv **is**) are always strings...

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the output you'd want is something like:

```
label
0,0,0,0,1
0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,1
```

Assuming your CSV data is in a list `csvdata` like so:

```py
csvdata = [[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0]] # ...
```

You would want to do something like this:

```py
with open("csv.csv", "w") as csv:
    csv.write("label1,label2,label3,label4,label5")
    for row in csvdata: # Get all the rows in our CSV
        is_first = True # make sure we don't write a comma on the first cell.
        for cell in row: # Now get each of the cells
            if not is_first: # Make sure this isn't our first cell
                csv.write(",") # Write a comma after the last line if it's not.
            csv.write(cell) # Write cell data
            is_first = False # Tell the program this isn't our first cell
```

Let's break down this code:

On the first line, we open our CSV file in **write** mode.
Then we write our header. Line endings are handled for us.

Now we iterate over each of our rows, and make a flag to tell the program this is the first cell.

Now, within that row, we iterate over our cells

If it's not the first cell in that row, write a comma to close the previous cell.

Then, make sure the program knows this isn't our first run on this row.

Comment: Thanks... But this code saved all zeros and ones in one long row! It doesn't save numbers under their headings(label1,label2,...)

Comment: It should. I hardcoded the header string for simplicity so you can just modify it.